# What eats but has no mouth

Tags: riddle

> What eats but has no mouth,
>
> Does not walk but has feet,
>
> Has millions of memories yet no brain,
>
> Is ancient yet young.

Hint:

> It starts with A.

Hint 2:

> It has 6 letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be

> Amoeba

I think the first two

> are self explanatory

There is no brain

> but it contains clues to ancient memories

Solving the fourth line as well.